# ошибочный вывод в простейшей программе, pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, for

```
for hours in range(24):
    for minutes in range(60):
        for seconds in range(60):
            print(hours,":",minutes, ':', seconds)
```

пишу такой код, и получаю вывод в консоли не с 0 : 0 : 0, а

```
 : 14 : 44
0 : 14 : 45
0 : 14 : 46
0 : 14 : 47
0 : 14 : 48
0 : 14 : 49
0 : 14 : 50
0 : 14 : 51
0 : 14 : 52
0 : 14 : 53
0 : 14 : 54
0 : 14 : 55
......
```

Comment: выводится все, просто в консоли стоит ограничение на количество символов, поэтому начинается не с начала

Comment: не знал об этом, спасибо, Danis!!!!!!

Comment: Начинается с начала, но когда символов становится слишком много, то первые начинают исчезать.